# strcmp in C++ not working

Tags: c++, strcmp

Why does the strcmp() function not work in the following code excerpt?:
(The program reads data from another file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct schokolade
{
    char name[20];
    int gewicht;
    int zutat_id[5];
    int menge_in_prozent[5];
};

struct zutat
{
    char name[20];
    float preis_pro_100gramm;
};


int main()
{
    char data[20];
    schokolade schokosorten[3];
    zutat zutaten[7];

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("schoki.txt");
    //Check for error:
    if(fin.fail()){
        cout << "Datei schoki.txt konnte nicht geöffnet werden." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int anzahl;
    char name_zutat[20];
    int anteil;

    while(fin.getline(data,20)){

        if(strcmp(data, "vollmilch_mandel")==0){ //DOES NOT WORK!
            strcpy(schokosorten[0].name, data); 
            ...
```

The code continues after this but it's not interesting for this question.

Comment: Is there an error? Please provide the output

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code and see what value the `data` holds. I bet it's not *vollmilch_mandel*.

Comment: @RawN Or at least print out the contents of data just before/after the comparison.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Make room for null terminator in the buffer, I mean instead of char data[20], declare it as data[21]. I don't now if that's the cause of problem though.

Comment: Possibly the input line contains leading or trailing spaces. Try to print out the lengths.

Comment: Use the string version of getline.